# Static link SDL2 on Linux

Tags: c, gcc, sdl, static-libraries, sdl-2

I am trying to statically link SDL2 on Linux, with the goal of creating a binary that doesn't require any libraries to be required on the system. I understand this will require statically linking more than just SDL2, such as SDL2's dependencies and things like libc, so help on that front would be appreciated as well. But right now I can't get SDL2 to statically link at all.

I am using GCC, and SDL 2.0.16 that I compiled and installed myself with the default configuration, which includes static libraries. I already had SDL2 installed through my package manager, so my installation went to `/usr/local/include/SDL2` and `/usr/local/lib`.

Running `/usr/local/bin/sdl2-config --cflags --static-libs` gives:

```
-I/usr/local/include/SDL2 -D_REENTRANT
-L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2 -lm -ldl -lpthread -lrt
```

No amount of messing around with these flags and `-static` have been able to produce a binary that doesn't dynamically link to SDL2. **How can I do it?**

Other flags I am using for other reasons are `-std=c89 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DNDEBUG -Os -g0 -s`

Being able to cross compile and do this would be great, but I understand that's a lot more complex. I've been trying to compile with [`zig cc`](https://andrewkelley.me/post/zig-cc-powerful-drop-in-replacement-gcc-clang.html) as that would allow cross-compilation later, but couldn't get it to work. I was able to get a build that didn't dynamically link to SDL2, but it would segfault.

---

In response to comments:

Running `pkg-config --static --cflags --libs /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/sdl2.pc` gives:

```
-I/usr/local/include/SDL2 -D_REENTRANT -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -lSDL2 -lm -ldl -lpthread -lrt
```

Using that creates a dynamically-linked executable, so not what I want. If I add `-static` I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_dynapi.o): in function `get_sdlapi_entry':
/home/makeworld/Software/SDL2-2.0.16/src/dynapi/SDL_dynapi.c:237: warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
```

Comment: Try `pkg-config --static --libs sdl2`, just in case. Also, how did you determine that it dynamically links against SDL2? Also, another option you have is to ship dynamic libraries with your binary, while either setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or [setting `rpath` while building](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath).

Comment: Some distributions tend to only ship .so files by default, can you confirm there is a .a file for SDL in `/usr/local/lib`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I updated my question for `pkg-config`. I determine the dynamic linking with `ldd` and/or `file`. As for shipping the dynamic libs, how would I do that? Thanks.

Comment: @Tzig Yes, there is a `.a` file. I am not using the distro version of SDL2, but one I compiled myself, which includes the static library by default.

Comment: @makeworld `-static` is to build static executable (i.e. that links no dynamic libraries at all). As you probably noticed, SDL uses `dlopen` a lot (in fact, even if you link statically with it, end user can still load their own updated SDL). To link only few static libraries you need to do somethinkg like `-Wl,-Bstatic -lSDL2 -Wl,-Bdynamic -lrest_of_dynamic_libs_you_require` (most notably, `-ldl`).

Comment: @keltar that worked! Thank you. I will post my command as an answer, but first I'm wondering how portable my executable is now. Is it possible to make more libraries static? It didn't work when I tried. Right now `libm`, `libdl`, `libpthread`, `librt`, and `libc` are still dynamically linked. That should be portable enough, because all those libraries are part of C/POSIX right?

Comment: @makeworld note that `ldd` is recursive. To get only direct dependencies you could use  `readelf -d your_executable`. It actually uses a lot more but SDL handles dynamic loading for you - e.g. you need X11 or wayland for graphics, alsa or pulseaudio for sound, etc., but they're not listed as your runtime dependencies. That's a good list of libraries, and there are good reasons *not* to link them statically.

Comment: @keltar Makes sense, thanks! `readelf` still gives the same list of libraries that `ldd` does, that I posted above. Are those being dynamically linked fine in terms of portability?

Comment: @makeworld yeah i'd say it is completely fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @HolyBlackCat and @keltar, I have been able to statically link SDL2.

I basically just used the output of `pkg-config` as provided in my question, but with the addition of `-Wl,-Bstatic` before `-lSDL2` and `-Wl,-Bdynamic` after it. This statically links SDL2, but dynamically links all the other libraries.

The final command is:

```
gcc your_code.c -o your_executable -I/usr/local/include/SDL2 -D_REENTRANT \
-L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags \
-Wl,-Bstatic -lSDL2 -Wl,-Bdynamic -lm -ldl -lpthread -lrt
```

If your build of SDL2 is installed elsewhere, just change the `/usr/local/include/SDL2` and `/usr/local/lib` part of the command to point to where the header files and `.a` files are respectively.

---

If I figure out how to cross-compile this setup, I will update this answer.

Comment: Have you figured out how to cross-compile this setup? It would be a huge help for me.

Comment: @SuperNoob I have not, and I am not actively looking into it anymore. I suspect using `zig cc` might be helpful.